# Developing an example for high school students about java interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I want to create an example of a java interface called NUMBER which two java classes FRACTION and COMPLEX implement.  I'm having a problem getting it to work.

For example:  I have a FRACTION method called add with the following header -

```
public Fraction add(Fraction f)
```

and a COMPLEX method called add with the following header -

```
public Complex add(Complex c).
```

When I define the method in the interface as

```
public Object add(Object o)
```

and compile Fraction, I get the error that my Fraction method does not overwrite the abstract method in the interface NUMBER.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. They have entirely different signatures. What would you expect this code to do: `Number n = new Fraction(); n.add("foo");`

Comment: Signature should not be changed in the implementation of interface methods, otherwise it will be entirely different methods from abstract method in the interface.

Comment: Should it be possible to add a Fraction to a Complex or a Complex to a Fraction?  If the answer is No, you'll want to use generics.  For example, you could make an interface `Operable<T>` with methods like `add(T rhs)` and `multiply(T rhs)`.  You'd then have `Fraction implements Operable<Fraction>` and `Complex implements Operable<Complex>`.  Or something similar with an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you compile, Java sees that the interface has a method called `add`, that outputs `Object`, but in the implementing class, it does not find any method name `add` that returns `Object`. You could instead make the interface's method return a `Number`, and cast the outputs based on that. You would have to keep in mind, though that all of the methods would have to return that `Number` type.

Another option could be to use generics. I'm not entirely sure how overriding methods with generic types works, but you might be able to use something that looks like this in your `Number` class:

```java
<T> T add(T t);
```

I am not entirely sure if this would work, as I have not worked with generics much in interfaces, but it might.

You might also be able to do something like this:

```java
public interface Number<T extends Number> {
    T add(T t);
}
```

Fraction:

```java
public class Fraction implements Number<Fraction> {
    @Override public Fraction add(Fraction f) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Fraction:

```java
public class Complex implements Number<Complex> {
    @Override public Complex add(Complex c) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Doing this will allow you to define the methods using more specific types, and should work quite well, but the two things would be that I am not sure if this is considered "best practice" to include the same class for the interface's type, and if you are comfortable showing your students generic types. They are a quite simple, yet powerful concept, but if you don't want to have to explain, the very first solution would probably suit you the best.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface should be of **Type Generic** to accommodate the interface method requirements of **return type** and **argument type** as well, please check the below code:

**First you have to define the generic interface class `Number` as:**

```
package com.oop.concepts;

public interface Number<T extends Number> {
    T add(T t);
}
```

**Once you have Generic add with with return type T and argument Type T you can implement it as below:**

```
package com.oop.concepts;

public class Fraction implements Number<Fraction> {

    private float a;

    public Fraction(float a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fraction{" +
            "a=" + a +
            '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Fraction add(Fraction n) {
        return new Fraction(this.a + n.a);
    }
}
```

**Same for complex class:**

```
package com.oop.concepts;

public class Complex implements Number<Complex> {

    private Double x;
    private Double y ;

    public Complex (Double x, Double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Complex{" +
            "x=" + x +
            ", y=" + y +
            '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Complex add(Complex n) {
        return new Complex(this.x + n.x, this.y + n.y);
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
package com.oop.concepts;

public class TestNumber {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Complex c1 = new Complex(3.4, 56.78);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(3.4, 56.78);

        Complex c3 = c1.add(c2);

        System.out.println(c3);

        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(3.4f);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(1.0f);
        Fraction f3 = f1.add(f2);

        System.out.println(f3);


    }
}
```

**Output of above Test cases:**

```
Complex{x=6.8, y=113.56}
Fraction{a=1.0}
Fraction{a=4.4}
```

Hope this make clear understanding of OOP concept along with **Generics in JAVA**

I have push these code into github, [have a look](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/tree/master/DS/src/com/oop/concepts)

Answer (score 0):

As some comments have pointed out, the signatures of your methods cannot change.

As your example stands, you would be putting the same code into both classes, which doesn't demonstrate inheritance in the best way.

One example that I have used and seen used many times is a using the area and perimeter of shapes. For brevity, my example only shows the example of one method, assuming variables and constructors have been made correctly.

```
public interface Shape{
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double volume();
}
```

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    ...
    public double area() {
        return width * height;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
    ...
    public double area() {
        return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }
    ...
}
```